# TypeError when checking vertical matches in game grid

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have a 13x13 multidimensional array, and I am attempting to check for vertical matches using this function:

```
function verticalMatch(row, col){
  for(var i = -1; i <= 1; i++) {
  if (gameBoard[row + i][col]==="O" && gameBoard[row + i + 1][col] === "O"
      && gameBoard[row +i-1][col] === "X" && gameBoard[row +i+2][col] === "X" ||

      gameBoard[row + i][col]==="O" && gameBoard[row + i - 1][col] === "O" 
      && gameBoard[row +i-2][col] === "X" && gameBoard[row +i+1][col] === "X"){
    return true;
   }
  }
 return false;       
}
```

I am testing this function like so:

```
if(verticalMatch(x,y)===true){
        console.log('Two O\s between two X\s vertically');
 }
```

When I run this code I keep getting the following error `TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined`. What could be causing this error, and what does it mean exactly?

Comment: Are you sure you aren't going out of bounds with your row indices?

Comment: How to I check for that exactly?

Comment: Are you ever calling verticalMatch for some row < 3?

Comment: If I place a piece in the uppermost square, I get this TypeError. I assume it's because I am calling verticalMatch on row 1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error occurs because you're checking rows with negative indices, which are undefined. Before you check `gameBoard[row + i][col]`, ensure that `row + i >= 0`. If it's negative, you don't need to check it, since it can't hold the appropriate piece.

Comment: So I'd put a conditional statement right after the initialization of the for-loop and then nest my if statement inside an if-statement that executes only when row + i >= 0?

Comment: @MahmudAdam You're also checking the value at row + i -1 and row + i - 2, so you probably need to check that those are >= 0 before accessing their values as well.

Comment: If I am doing diagonals then do I have to check row + 1 - 1, col + 1 - 1, row + i -2, col + i - 2 and so forth? I am not sure how to check the boundaries for the diagonal rows.

Comment: @MahmudAdam The key thing to think about is ensuring that you're never trying to check an index that you haven't defined. In this case, making sure you never go below 0 or above 12

Answer (score 2):

Depending on your `row` value, you could easily be accessing indices that are < 0. For example if `row === 1` then there would be an access at `gameBoard[1 + -1 - 1]` which is the same as `gameBoard[-1]`.